# How to add WebCal/iCalendar to Google Calendar by a direct link

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar, webcal

You can add a calendar hosted on Google to your Google Calendar account by a direct link (for example as on [Holidays in Australia](https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=en.australian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com) - the button in the bottom left corner - if you click on it, the calendar will be added to your account).
I have a webcal calendar on my site and I want to add a button like in the example which points to my calendar.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this with this link:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=
```

With after the = symbol the link to your ICS file. For example:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=http://www.example.com/calendar.ics
```

Comment: Thanks, also I think the calendar link should be escaped (i.e. with urlencode in php).

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to subscribe to a calendar, not just events (as in, .ics files)? Google Calendar does a GET request against my non-ics resource, instead of PROPFIND.

Comment: I tried, it failed mysteriously. And the solution apparently was this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23473919/google-calendar-add-by-url-requirements I just spent an hour on this, but I'm somehow glad it's working now.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work any more - i get the error "This email address isn't associated with an active Google Calendar account: https://shorturl.at/dwD09. Please check the email address and try again."