# Adding a webcal calendar to calendar app via API or URI protocol

Tags: android, outlook, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am trying to create a calendar export for my sports organization. I get the data from an external API (the match dates change sometimes) and format it to form .ics files. I got a .ics feed up and running so that is not a problem since I can manually sync it via google calendar and outlook.

The thing I am trying to find is a way to automatically have it added to the users' calendar via for example the [google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api) or [outlook calendar API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-1.0&preserve-view=true) or even using the webcal protocol to get a prompt on the users' phone/computer to add it to their calendar app. But it also seems like that is not supported on android phones?

The api's also don't seem to have this support, both google and outlook only provide a way to add a calender by supplying a name for it in the request body. ref: [google](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/insert), [outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-calendars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

I hope someone can get me through this or provide another alternative. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903822/how-to-add-webcal-icalendar-to-google-calendar-by-a-direct-link) post that I can directly link users to the webcal link and this works, but it opens a browser the google calendar instead of the app, is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach would be to manually import the ics file into the Google Calendar of a specific Google account and then use the API with the `events: list` method to list all the events created by that file and retrieve their `eventId` parameter, then use it along with the `calendarId` parameter to update each event and automatically invite the users to all the events.

Since you mentioned that the dates of the events can change sometimes, with this method you will make sure that all the invited users get notifications whenever there is an update so they don't miss any changes.

##### References:

- [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list)
- [Events: update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update)

Comment: Yea I will try and implement it with google API then, I thought it would be quite easy to do with webcal since it would work on all platform (I though) but I guess not so. Thanks for the reply and will check as answer when it works :)